# How can I successfully export a Developer Signed app from Xcode 13?

Tags: xcode, macos

It sounds like a really simple problem to solve - but it's really boiling my noggin, and Apple has (so far, at least) been no help in solving it (I've raised a bug report).  I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this problem, and how they went about solving it.

Whenever I try to export an application for distribution with Developer ID, whether I Notarise or not, it crashes:

```
Process:               Xcode [1225]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               13.0 (19234)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-19234000000000000~16 (13A233)
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1225]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-09-29 19:40:33.078 +0100
OS Version:            macOS 11.4 (20F71)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        EC195B68-B7C5-BD3E-C8A4-C886AAA00F1F

Sleep/Wake UUID:       CE0BBFA7-96D9-4A1B-A784-D30662D0E3B8

Time Awake Since Boot: 2400 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1200 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        12  Dispatch queue: ConcurrentQueue: -[IDEDistributionPackagingStepViewController viewDidInstall]_block_invoke

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 13A233
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-19207/DVTFoundation/FilePaths/DVTFilePath.m:908
Details:  str should be a string, but it is nil
Object:   <DVTFilePath>
Method:   +filePathForPathString:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x2c5770a50>{number = 36, name = (null)}
Open FDs: 58/7168
```

To add to the confusion, I can upload to the App Store with no difficulty whatsoever.

The signing settings are:

```
Automatically Manage Signing
Team - my Developer Team Name
Bundle Identifier - the name of my application
Provisioning Profile - None Required
Signing Certificate - Development
```

When I try *not* signing automatically, and I select my Provisioning Profile, I get a Status of:

```
Provisioning profile xxx.yyy.zzz doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Development: Headbanger (AAAAAAAAAAA)"
```

The weird thing is that when I sign in to my Developer Account, my ID isn't AAAAAAAAAAA it's BBBBBBBBBBB (obviously neither AAAA... or BBBB... - that's just for the purposes of illustration).  I'm utterly perplexed.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this might help someone else.  It turns out (in this instance) that the problem was with some compiled code (my own) that I was importing to use as a plug in.

This code wasn't getting signed correctly, and this seems to have been the cause of the crash in Xcode.  Removing the copy stage (in build phases) solved the problem.  Signing the code properly allowed me to re-add it in the build phase without causing a problem during notarisation later.

The App Store version didn't contain this copy stage - so the plug in didn't exist and the problem didn't occur.

I still have a bug report open with Apple because, although the root cause was my own fault in this instance, Xcode shouldn't crash in these circumstances - and it would be useful if it produced a more helpful error message!  Searching the internet, it seems that I'm not the only person to have received this error message either.